# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'" even though azure-cli-core was installed

Tags: python, pip, azure-cli

The various `azure-cli`* modules were installed via `pip3.10`:

```
python3.10 -m pip list

2023-03-24T23:57:52.8637926Z azure-cli                               2.46.0
2023-03-24T23:57:52.8638330Z azure-cli-core                          2.46.0
2023-03-24T23:57:52.8638523Z azure-cli-telemetry                     1.0.8
2023-03-24T23:57:52.8638722Z azure-common                            1.1.28
2023-03-24T23:57:52.8638929Z azure-core                              1.26.3
```

But when running `pytest` using the same `python3.10` `azure.cli.core` can not be imported?

```
 + python3.10 -m pytest -s -rA
```

```
2023-03-25T00:01:08.3698899Z =============================

 ________________________ ERROR collecting test session _________________________
2023-03-25T00:01:08.3796409Z /usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module

from azure.cli.core import AzCommandsLoader
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'
2023-03-25T00:01:08.3800743Z =========================== short test summary info ============================
2023-03-25T00:01:08.3800996Z ERROR  - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'
```

Comment: Try python3.10 -m pytest --version

Comment: I frequently  use `python -V` or `python3 -V` to disambiguate. What are you aiming at in this case?

Comment: Try using python3

Comment: why? the python3.10 is *more* explicit

Comment: python -V used for python2 or python3

Comment: Maybe try to tie this back to the original question: how does that get us to more understanding of the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252764/discussion-between-westcoastprojects-and-rithwikbojja).